# Raising a bad request 400 exception in a ListAPIView

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Im trying to raise a 400 exception when the user does not provide a token or when the token is not valid  my code is below :

this is my exceptions.py file :

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import APIException, PermissionDenied


class MissingTokenException(APIException):
    status_code = 400
    default_detail = 'Your request does not contain token'
    default_code = 'no_token'


class InvalidTokenException(APIException):
    status_code = 400
    default_detail = 'Your request contain invalid token'
    default_code = 'invalid_token'
```

this is my views.py file :

```
class ListProductsOfCategory(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'category_id'

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        token = self.request.META.get("HTTP_TOKEN", "")
        if not token:
            # here I wan to raise an error saying that no token provided.
           raise MissingTokenException
        if not UserAccess.objects.filter(accessToken=token).exists():
            # here I wan to raise an error saying that token provided is not valid.
           raise InvalidTokenException
        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        category_id = self.kwargs.get(self.lookup_url_kwarg)
        return Product.objects.filter(category_id=category_id)
```

Im using postman to test my APIs:

[image]

please if any one can help Im new to django and python.

Comment: According to your screenshot, your exception is being raised properly. What are you expecting that isn't happening?

Comment: the error raised is 500 internal server error, I want it to be 400 bad request , I also want to return a JSON message that describes the error

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/) has an example of how to handle custom exceptions, setting the status code properly.

Comment: I checked the documentation before asking, if it worked with me, I wouldn't be asking..

Answer (score 1):

DRF handles [most of its internals within the `dispatch` function](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/views.py#L471-L498), including catching the `APIException`.
If you want to raise an `APIException` outside of it - which is what your code is doing - you'll also have to catch the exception and call the exception handler [as does DRF](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/views.py#L494-L498).
Please also note that you would miss content negotiation and a few other things.

A better way to deal with it is to perform the check though authentication and permissions.